# exclude specific path from routing in angular 2+

Tags: angular, router

My angular route config is as below:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'mgmt', ... },
  { path: 'about', ... },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundCmp }
];
```

But now on a page, there's a link (`<a href="/help/en/index.html" target="_blank">`) to help pages, which are static resources hosted on the same server. With the above route config, apparently it will be matched to others `**` - page not found.

Let's say we cannot host help resources in another domain, is there any way to exclude `/help/**` path from angular routing? or do you think this is a valid feature request for angular to support?

Comment: I think you should configure server not to redirect to `index.html` from `/help/**` path

Comment: Any luck ????????

Comment: @mp3por this is not supported in angular for now, so I choose to create a dedicated context for all angular routes, while `/help/*` static resources is still served by the same server.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @KhaledRamadan as I commented above, I added a context for angular app. Using base href in my case, all angular routes are now `/ui/**`, and I added necessary config in server end so that all `/ui/*` requests are routed to `index.html` (client routing), while `/help/*` is routed to static help resources.

Comment: ok @RoyLing thanks for your reply

Comment: Have you seen this Post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150393/how-to-redirect-to-an-external-url-from-angular2-route-without-using-component

Comment: @SilvesterSchn. Thanks for sharing the link, and that's another interesting topic, but not exactly the same problem I was trying to solve in this question though.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here [angular 2 exclude url in routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271170/angular-2-exclude-url-in-routing) the only solution seems to set `useHash: true` in your RouterModule config:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        {
          path: 'login',
          loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
        },
        {
          path: '**',
          redirectTo: ''
        },
      ],
      {
        useHash: true,
        onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'
      }
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I fixed the issue using another solution, see the comments in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @RoyLing, could you detail your solution ?

Comment: @user1767316 serving the angular app from another web context :)